# Javascript Date() in ReactJS: How to accept input as GMT/UTC and convert it into ISO string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, reactjs

Currently the input is `"12 09 2016 00:00:00"` and should assume it is in inputted as GMT date and time. But rather, it accepts it as local and converts it as such. And when it is turned to `ISOString()`, it converts it to GMT, and adds the time difference.

How can I take an input in `"12 09 2016 00:00:00"` format, take it as GMT/UTC, and do `.toISOString()` to turn it into the ISO format, `"2016-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"`?

```
var dateAndTime = new Date("12 09 2016 00:00:00")
//Returns: "Fri Dec 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)"
//Want it to return: "Fri Dec 09 2016 00:00:00 (GMT)"

var gmtDateAndTime = dateAndTime.toISOString();
//Returns: "2016-12-09T08:00:00.000Z"
//Want it to return: "2016-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Thank you and will be sure to vote up and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another Date constructor. The default constructor creates time in your local timezone.

Replace this:

```
var dateAndTime = new Date("12 09 2016 00:00:00")
```

With this:

```
var dateAndTime = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 09, 12, 0, 0, 0));
```

If you can't convert your string ("12 09 2016 00:00:00") manually to the individual UTC parameters, you can use this (but unreliable especially in IE):

```
var utcDate = Date.parse("12 09 2016 00:00:00");
```

Comment: Do not use Date.parse (or the Date constructor) for parsing strings as it is largely implementation dependent. Months are zero indexed so "12 09 2016 00:00:00" should be converted using `new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 8, 12))`. Note that if time values aren't supplied, they default to 0 (hence milliseconds defaulted to zero even though you didn't supply a value). ;-)

Comment: `Date.parse("12 09 2016 00:00:00")` returns NaN in Safari. If it's parsed at all, it will return a number, not a Date so `utcDate.getUTCFullYear()` will throw an error.

Comment: @RobG So is there a better option without having to manually convert my string to individual UTC parameters, and only able to accept `"12 09 2016 00:00:00"` as the input?

Comment: Not really. Date strings can be in many different formats, so if you just give it to a parser without specifying the format, you're leaving it to chance. Your own function only needs 3 lines of code, or you can use a library (e.g. [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha), [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com)) with several thousand lines, but you **must** specify the format.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Date to parse happenstance date strings. Date.parse only works in a well defined manner when the input is an ISO8061 string.

From "15.9.4.2 Date.parse" in the ECMA 5 standard:

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

and from 15.9.1.15 the string format recognized is

> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

which looks very much the ISO string you want to arrive at, not start with.

Alternative choices to solve the issue might include:

1. write your own function to parse a user input string. Has the problem that "12 09 2016" could mean "Dec 9 2016" or "Sep 12 2016" depending on user locale.
2. Use a date and time library. Moment.js is frequently mentioned in SO answers regarding such libraries.
3. Use the output of a date picker or validated data from a data base. Avoids issues with locale dependent formats.
4. Hard code conversion to ISO8061 format *without* parsing may be an option if the input string is **absolutely guaranteed** to be in "mm dd yyyy hh:mm:ss" format, as for example using

   ```
   function isoFromZ( str) {
      return str.substr(6,4) + "-" +
             str.substr(0,2) + "-" +
             str.substr(3,2) + "T" + 
             str.substring(11) + ".000Z";
   }
   ```

In summary extract the UTC date and time components from a custom input string *before* creating a `Date` object. If extraction produced an ISO8061 date string it can be passed directly to the `Date` constructor as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I take an input in "12 09 2016 00:00:00" format, take it as
>   GMT/UTC, and do .toISOString() to turn it into the ISO format,
>   "2016-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"?

It seems you just want to reformat the string, so just do that:

```js
// Reformat string in MM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss format to 
// ISO 8601 UTC
function formatDateStringISO(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[2] + '-' + b[0] + '-' + b[1] +
         'T' + b[3] + ':' + b[4] + ':' + b[5] + '.000Z';
}

console.log(formatDateStringISO('12 09 2016 00:00:00'))
```

If you want to parse the string to a Date then output an ISO 8601 format string, do that:

```js
// Parse string in MM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss format
// If date string is invalid, returns an invalid Date
function parseDateAsUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(b[2], --b[0], b[1], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
  // Validate date
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Valid date             Invalid date
['12 09 2016 00:00:00', '12 34 2016 00:00:00'].forEach(function(s) {
  var d = parseDateAsUTC(s);
  console.log(s + ' => ' + d[isNaN(d)? 'toString' : 'toISOString']());
});
```